# Android, How to Play song while i'm capturing video from camera?

Tags: android, video, intentfilter

when user clicks a button i nee to direct him to a page which it has list of songs. Then when an items selected by user the i need to play song and let him to capture movie together. Its something like karaoke.

Is it possible? please tell me how can i find a reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I can tell because my cam playing button click sound when I am recording.
I don't think you need a service for that, just try using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right i could stream music during capturing video (I didn't use service). Thanks

Comment: Headset is connected to the device,  Will it get recorded while playing song in the media player?

Comment: @shijil It could. It depends on what the mic will catch and how close it's going to be to it. You can't how ever record directly from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use of service will help in this case. For this you need to create two services, one for recording video and other for playing music. Through your main activity control both.

I hope it solve the work. But as per the devices seen like samsung devices, they dont provide this functionality. When camera recording is done, you cant play music.

Logically using service we can do the task.

Let me know if it works :)